# How to capitalize an attr_accessor

Tags: ruby

I am doing a project in Ruby:

```
class Book
  # write your code here
  attr_accessor :title

end
```

When I run `rake` in the terminal, the title gets set to "inferno" but it should be capitalized. How can I do it with an `attr_accessor`?

I tried using

```
title = title.capitalize
```

but it throws an error.

Rake:

```
Book
  title
    should capitalize the first letter (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

  1) Book title should capitalize the first letter
     Failure/Error: expect(@book.title).to eq("Inferno")

       expected: "Inferno"
            got: "inferno"

       (compared using ==)
     # ./05_book_titles/book_titles_spec.rb:26:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.01101 seconds (files took 0.14779 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure
```

Comment: please show your code

Comment: @AJFaraday Hmm? [doc capitalize](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/String.html#method-i-capitalize)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages.

Comment: Okay, capitalise is the right method... where are you calling the ‘title =‘ line? Is it in the Book class? If so, if it in the initialize method? In which case you’d need to use ‘self.title =‘

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta its at the top. Above the errors shown by rake,

Comment: You've shown 3 lines of code defining the class, and one other separate line `title = title.capitalize`. Code lines aren't independent; classes, functions, and tests usually consist of a bunch of consecutive lines of code and the exact sequence of the lines of code matter.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write your own setter method for this, so first change the `attr_accessor` to just `attr_reader`, then define the method

```
def title=(val)
  @title = val.capitalize
end
```

Comment: @Amadan oh yeah, good catch.